# Ansible AWX group/tags not in sync with AWS after changing values

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

The Ansible AWX Dynamic inventory initially works great and creates host groups based on the AWS tags assigned to the ec2 hosts in an AWS account. However, if I then make a change to the tag value in AWS e.g. change from DEV to PROD and then re-run source sync in AWX, I find that it pulls in the new tag/group but does not remove the original tag/group assigned to the very same host.

This means I have stale tags associated with my hosts. I now have a group called DEV and PROD associated with the same host which is not in sync with my AWS tagging.

Deleting all groups/hosts and then re-syncing is not an option because we pass variables at the inventory group level. This would mean we need to re-insert the variable for all groups each time we make changes/add new tags to our AWS inventory.

Is this there a workaround for this? otherwise, this makes dynamic inventory not quite great.

See yml file used for dynamic inventory below

Thanks

```
plugin: aws_ec2
cache: no
regions:
  - eu-west-1
  - eu-west-2
  - eu-west-3
#filters:
#  "instance-state-name": running
strict_permissions: False
hostnames:
  - tag:Name
groups:
  ec2: true
keyed_groups:
# Add hosts to tag_Name_Value groups for each Name/Value tag pair
- prefix: tag
  key: tags
# Create a group per region e.g. aws_region_eu_west_2
- key: placement.region
  prefix: aws_region
compose:
  ansible_host: private_ip_address
```

Comment: This is strange, I tested this in my own environment and it seems to pick up the latest tags (after I modify the tag value) and assign the groups accordingly.
Could you try to re-run the inventory script after explicitly setting the value of `cache` parameter to `no` in your aws_ec2.yml file.

Comment: Hi, i have added the "cache: no" value to my aws_ec2.yml file. You can see the code above. This has not worked. I tried changing a tag value again and although it detects the change and assigns it to the correct group in AWX, it still shows in the original group so isn't quite synchronising.

Comment: I have managed to resolve this issue by checking the "overwrite" button in the > inventories > sources (tab) through the AWX console. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the box in the source of dynamic inventory to over override the old values.

If checked, any hosts and groups that were previously present on the external source but are now removed will be removed from the Tower inventory. Hosts and groups that were not managed by the inventory source will be promoted to the next manually created group or if there is no manually created group to promote them into, they will be left in the "all" default group for the inventory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I discovered the same a few days ago. I deleted the default group but all of the inventory was dynamically pulled from AWS so would be assigned to the dedicated inventory